# GORM, Envers and @NotAudited relationships or adding annotations to hasMany-relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using hibernate envers with Grails, defining some entities with @Audited to let them audited by the API. Some entities should not be audited, so I am defining @Audited(... NOT_AUDITED) which runs also smoothly.

But this time, I have a relationship defined following

```
static hasMany = { foos : Foo }
```

Foo is also declared as NOT_Audited at class level, but envers is ignoring this and searching for an AUDIT table. However, I have seen that it might be necessary to add the annotation @NotAudited to the relationship to inform envers that the type should not be audited.

So, I have tried:

```
static hasMany = {@NotAudited foos : Foo }

// Or desperately:
@NotAudited
static hasMany = { foos : Foo }
```

Either it seems that my approach is false or that GORM is ignoring the annotation.

Does anyone have experience with it where it is not enough to define "Not_Audited" at class level like

```
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
class Foo{
   ...
}
@Audited
class Bar{
   static hasMany = { foos : Foo }
   ...
}
```

EDIT: Maybe good to mention that 
     static hasMany = {@NotAudited foos : Foo }

runs into compilation error. So, maybe my problem is just how to add the annotation to the relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you found your answer, but you need to overload the getter, and put the annotation on it :

```
@NotAudited
def getFoos() {foos}
```

At least, it works for direct associations...