# GORM envers @NotAudited one-to-many relationship Not persisted

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In my Grails (2.4.3) project I'm trying to use Hibernate Envers directly without the plugin. Everything works fine as long as the domains don't have a relationship. 
I have a very common scenario where one Audited class has a direct association to a Not Audited Class.

Referring to [GORM, Envers and @NotAudited relationships or adding annotations to hasMany-relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354237/gorm-envers-and-notaudited-relationships-or-adding-annotations-to-hasmany-rela) I got the auditing on the main class to work but then realised the associated entity is not persisted. I tried all the combinations in the above referred link but did not help. 
Here's a snippet of my Code:

```
@Audited
class Foo{
  Bar bar
  ...

  @NotAudited
  def getBar(){bar}

}

class Bar{
   ...
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the return type of `getBar` from `def` to `Bar`.